# Cannot get ValidStates of WindowsInstaller features

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I've encountered a problem when I try to retrieve the valid states of all features within an MSI package using the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Installer class.

I want to copy the ValidStates property of each FeatureInfo within a Session. However when doing so I get a "Handle is in an invalid state." exception.
If I print each of these values out using Console.WriteLine() or step through the code in Visual Studio there is no exception.

I am at a loss as to what is preventing me from doing this.
Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
var featureDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mPath))
    return featureDictionary;

try
{
    Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);
    using (var session = Installer.OpenPackage(mPath, true))
    {           
        foreach (var feature in session.Features)
        {
            try
            {
                var states = feature.ValidStates.Select((state) => state.ToString());
                featureDictionary.Add(feature.Name, states.ToArray());
            }
            catch (InstallerException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (InstallerException) { }

return featureDictionary;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem appears to be that you are opening the MSI as a file. Since you haven't posted its declaration, or how it is set, I'm assuming that mpath means it's a path to the file. Your OpenPackage method parameters seem to indicate this too. You're getting that error because you are trying to open the MSI file as a file during the actual install, and failing.

The way to get hold of the database for the running install is to use Session.Database.

You can't open the running MSI as a file during the install perhaps for the same reason you can't run an MSI file that you have open with Orca, a simple file sharing violation. When you step through with Visual Studio you're simply accessing the static file and getting default values and the file isn't being used for an install. The other issue is that there can only be one Session object per process (as the OpenPackage docs say) and you are attempting to get a second one while there is already a Session object associated with the handle of the install.

As a custom action it needs to be sequenced after CostFinalize.

Windows Installer conditional expressions such as !feature-state will tell you what state the feature is in, because it's usually better to avoid code where Windows Installer will just give you the answer.

Comment: Why can I not open the MSI as a file?

Comment: You want the feature states from the running install - you can't get that by opening a static MSI file on disk, whether it's the one you're running or some other random MSI file. You get that by using the handle for the current running installation, that's exactly what the handle is for, to reference the current *installing* database with all its changing dynamic states.

Comment: But if I print out the values I can access them. Unless there is something I'm missing in the difference of what that is doing?